# new google reCAPTCHA for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I have already used the new version of google reCaptcha with my asp.net project and it worked fine until I recognized some errors when I tested it. For example, when I enter wrong password or username other than that even when I leave some parts empty I get an error from captcha. I looked on google but I couldnt find any thing to help me, I found examples or documentation for php but I need the asp.net version of them. Any help or a link would be great.

Comment: How an username and a password are related to reCaptcha in your project? I've been using reCaptcha for years and can't think of any relation here.

Comment: recaptcha is in the sign in section I have no idea why they react like this but I may have made some mistake attaching captcha to my project. I couldnt find any documentation for recaptcha in asp.net version. Anything would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using the version that has the "I'm not a robot" checkbox or the one that you enter the text from the image?

Comment: If I am understood correct, please visit this link for more clarity on integration and proper error handling http://www.dotnet4techies.com/2016/12/how-to-integrate-googles-im-not-robot.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using "I am not a robt" reCAPTCHA here is detailed article:
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Google-New-reCaptcha-I-am-not-a-robot-using-asp-n

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.